# Using classes like lists in java

Tags: java

So I tried searching through Stackoverflow and couldn't find something helpful. If there is such link, please point me to it.

Let's say I have class in Java with variables looking like this:

```
    class Example {
      public type a;
      public Example next;
}
```

Obviously, I want to use this class as list where I can add more elements on the end using object variable next.

My confusion comes when iterating through these.
Let's suppose I already made object of `class Example` called test and added few elements on the next variable.
While using this object in method, is there difference if I use:

```
test = test.next;
```

or if I use:

```
Example test2 = test;
test2 = test2.next
```

I suppose those two mean the same, are references on same object so iterating one also means iterating the second. When I return from method, "pointer" on that object goes back to my starting object.
Is that correct?

Now I have a problem if I want to delete one of the elements.
Assuming what I wrote before is correct I can't just write `test = test.next;` because everything I do will get "dispelled" once I exit method.

How should I approach this problem if I want to delete one of the elements in my "list"?
One thing more; I can't use LinkedLists or anything else, this is how I am supposed to do my assignment.

Comment: Use a [LinkedList<Example>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, I see here a misunderstood of variables and references

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing the very standard linked list deletion algorithm. Here's a [sample Google hit](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/linked-list/delete/) for it, but you can just search for yourself and follow anything.

You may also just actually use a Java [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

You may also try reading the actual source code in Java for the [remove](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.remove%28int%29) method for LinkedList.

I also want to point out you're not "using classes like lists." You're just implementing a LinkedList, and choosing to call your class Example, instead of List or LinkedList or SinglyLinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

What you are look for is Java iterators. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm) for some help. Essentially, you should create a typed collection in Java e.g. `List<Example>` and use the iterator on that list. `List` comes from `java.util`.